# Upload e Donwload de arquivos JSF + Primefaces + Mysql

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Como recuperar o nome do arquivo salvo como BLOB do banco de dados e exibir na tela? Estou usando um laço de repetição, para recuperar, o valo salvo na coluna do banco de dados, porem retorna valores de memória ([B@2248bd40):[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra inconsistência, que está ocorrendo é: Quando o usuário realiza o Upload para o banco de dados, o arquivo é salvo com sucesso (qualquer arquivo), porém para executar o donwload devo informar o código, e só permite a saída do arquivo na extensão formatada no código fonte (Exemplo: pdf, doc, etc). O problema é, que só vai sair de acordo com a extensão definida. Tem alguma forma de executar o donwload do arquivo em formato original, que foi salvo?

Segue o método:

```
public void download() {
    ResultSet rs;
    try {

        Connection con = Conexao.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT image FROM uploadfile WHERE codigo = (?) ");
        st.setInt(1, codigo);

        rs = st.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
            file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "Arquivo.pdf");
        }
        con.close();

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Exito", " File descarregado com sucesso.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

    } catch (Exception erro) {
        erro.printStackTrace();
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Erro ao executar download.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa armazenar os arquivos no banco? Não pode salvar em algum storage ou coisa do tipo? No banco salve apenas o caminho do arquivo. Eu, particularmente, acho muito mais fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível recuperar o nome de um arquivo BLOB pelo Java, seria necessário converter este BLOB para algum outro tipo de objeto para isto, o que não seria muito legal de se fazer.

Neste caso o que te indico a fazer é:

- Salvar o nome do arquivo em uma outra coluna do banco de dado; ou
- Alterar a forma de armazenagem do arquivo para recuperá-lo de alguma forma mais simples sem utilizar o BLOB.

É isto, seguindo sua abordagem atual não imagino que seja fácil realizar esta funcionalidade, talvez trocando a abordagem tudo fique mais fácil. Boa sorte!